# Replace single quote character on EVAL field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, replace, eval

I am trying to remove the single quote charater in the field using the replace() command.  The replace works fine if I user an alpha character for removal but not with a single quote ( ' ).

```
<asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" 
     text='<%# (DirectCast(Eval("NAME"), String).Replace("'", ""))%>' >
</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to escape any single quotes in the string.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" 
     text='<%# (DirectCast(Eval("NAME"), String).Replace("\'", ""))%>' >
</asp:Label>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get a: 'Server TAg Not Well-formed Error"

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a function

```
<%# DoSomething(DirectCast(Eval("NAME"), String))%>

Function DoSomething(Byval s As String)

    Return s.Replace("'", "")
End Function
```

Comment: This command is in my ASPx page and the field is being populated in a gridview.  Not sure how this woudl all be tied together.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" 
     text='<%# Replace(DirectCast(Eval("NAME"), String),"'", "")%>'
</asp:Label>
```

**Update**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" 
         text='<%# Replace(Eval("NAME"),"'", "")%>'
    </asp:Label>
```

Comment: Getting error:  ErrorID 3822574: THE SERVER TAG IS NOT WELL FORMED.

Comment: I have made some changes in my initial answer .please try both

Comment: Also tried:  <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" 
                                text='<%# Eval("NAME").ToString().Replace("'", "")%>' >